# How does Jenkins' 'emulate clean checkout' option work?

Tags: svn, jenkins

Specifically I am wanting to know how to do the 'delete unversioned/ignored files' part of the command. I want to do this so I can emulate a clean checkout myself, our repository is big and a full checkout takes a fair while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how Jenkins does this, but I'd assume it uses `svn status` to find unversioned/ignored files.

Here's 2 powershell scripts I use to do this:

```
#remove_ignored.ps1 (only removes ignored files, leaves unversioned)

param([switch] $WhatIf)

# Find all items with the status of I in svn
# Strip the leading status code and whitespace
# Grab the item for said path (either FileInfo or DirectoryInfo)
$paths = (svn status --no-ignore | Where-Object {$_.StartsWith('I')} | ForEach-Object {$_.SubString(8)} | ForEach-Object {Get-Item -Force $_})

$paths | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not $WhatIf) {
        # Check if the path still exists, in case it was a nested directory or something strange like that
        if ($_.Exists) {
            # If its a directory info, tell it to perform a recursive delete
            if ($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) { $_.Delete($true) }
            else { $_.Delete() }
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Deleted $_"
}
```

---

```
#remove_unversioned.ps1 (removes both ignored and unversioned files)
param([switch] $WhatIf)

# Find all items with the status of I or ? in svn
# Strip the leading status code and whitespace
# Grab the item for said path (either FileInfo or DirectoryInfo)
$paths = (svn status --no-ignore | Where-Object {$_.StartsWith('I') -or $_.StartsWith('?')} | ForEach-Object {$_.SubString(8)} | ForEach-Object {Get-Item -Force $_})

$paths | ForEach-Object {
    if (-not $WhatIf) {
        # Check if the path still exists, in case it was a nested directory or something strange like that
        if ($_.Exists) {
            # If its a directory info, tell it to perform a recursive delete
            if ($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) { $_.Delete($true) }
            else { $_.Delete() }
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Deleted $_"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This option is implemented in `UpdateWithCleanUpdater`.  From the [source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/subversion/UpdateWithCleanUpdater.java),

```
@Override
protected void preUpdate(ModuleLocation module, File local) throws SVNException, IOException {
    listener.getLogger().println("Cleaning up " + local);

    clientManager.getStatusClient().doStatus(local, null, SVNDepth.INFINITY, false, false, true, false, new ISVNStatusHandler() {
        public void handleStatus(SVNStatus status) throws SVNException {
            SVNStatusType s = status.getCombinedNodeAndContentsStatus();
            if (s == SVNStatusType.STATUS_UNVERSIONED || s == SVNStatusType.STATUS_IGNORED || s == SVNStatusType.STATUS_MODIFIED) {
                listener.getLogger().println("Deleting "+status.getFile());
                try {
                    File f = status.getFile();
                    if (f.isDirectory())
                        hudson.Util.deleteRecursive(f);
                    else
                        f.delete();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new SVNException(SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorCode.UNKNOWN, e));
                }
            }
        }
    }, null);
}
```

Looks like the code uses SVNKit to get SVN status and then delete all unversioned, ignored, *and modified* files and directories.

It surprised me that modified files are deleted instead of reverted, but they will get pulled back in through the SVN update anyway.